# Msbuild batch - if any build fails than skip the last one

Tags: batch

I have this batch that builds some projects using msbuild.

What I want to do is to skip building my-last.proj if any of the above builds fail: my-proj1.proj to my-proj5.proj using environment variables.

I'm sure that there is another cleaner way to do this, but so far I just can't figure it out.

```
msbuild /target:Win32 my-proj1.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED32=1
)
msbuild /target:X64 my-proj1.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED64=1
)

msbuild /target:ManagedWin32 my-proj1.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED32=1
)
msbuild /target:ManagedX64 my-proj1.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED64=1
)

msbuild /target:Win32 my-proj2.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED32=1
)
msbuild /target:X64 my-proj2.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED64=1
)

msbuild /target:Win32 my-proj3.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED32=1
)
msbuild /target:Win32 my-proj4.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED32=1
)
msbuild /target:Win32 my-proj5.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED32=1
)

IF NOT "%FAILED32%" == "1" (
msbuild /target:setup32 my-last.proj
)

msbuild /target:X64 my-proj3.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED64=1
)
msbuild /target:X64 my-proj4.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED64=1
)
msbuild /target:X64 my-proj5.proj
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 ( 
    set /p BUILDFAILED64=1
)

IF NOT "%FAILED64%" == "1" (
msbuild /target:setup64 my-last.proj
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It looks like you have figured out exactly what this site is about. You just passed the "first post" test with ease!

Comment: @Simon André Forsberg - Thanks, I'm glad that Code Review exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant `set %BUILDFAILEDxx%=1`? `/p` is for prompting interactively (or reading from a file).

Otherwise, except a minor typo `%BUILDFAILED32%` instead of just `%FAILED32%` (and same for 64bit builds), this looks good (and "clean") enough for me.

You could get rid of the parentheses (for the sake of it?) if you wrote each `if` on a single line.

Comment: @Jamal oops, thanks for the "codifying", I'll look up how to do it properly. As for the space before the question mark, sorry I'm French :-) so I may do it again.

Comment: Did you expect more ? Apart from reorganizing the order of builds (either by number 32b-1,64b-1,32b-2,... or by regrouping all the 32 and 64bit ones) I think this is the optimal & "cleanest" solution (with environment variables, in cmd).

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to localize any environment changes.

You should initialize your variables to a known state at the beginning, otherwise you could get the wrong result.

You have a lot of redundant code that can be eliminated by using a CALLed subroutine

You can use the `||` operator to conditionally execute code if the previous command failed. I find it simpler than using IF ERRORLEVEL.

You can save a bit of typing by storing code in a variable to be used as a simple macro.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "failed32="
set "failed64="
set "build=call :build"

%build% Win        32 my-proj1
%build% X          64 my-proj1
%build% ManagedWin 32 my-proj1
%build% ManagedX   64 my-proj1
%build% Win        32 my-proj2
%build% X          64 my-proj2
%build% Win        32 my-proj3
%build% Win        32 my-proj4
%build% Win        32 my-proj5

if not defined failed32 msbuild /target:setup32 my-last.proj

%build% X          64 my-proj3
%build% X          64 my-proj4
%build% X          64 my-proj5

if not defined failed64 msbuild /target:setup64 my-last.proj
exit /b


:build  target  size  proj
msbuild /target:%1%2 %3.proj || set failed%%2=1
exit /b
```